# Radio button causes browser to jump to the top

Tags: css, radio-button

## Problem:

When clicking on a label (for a radio button that has been intentionally hidden by positioning it off-screen), the browser undesirably jumps to the top of the page.

*Note: This issue is inconsistent across different browsers -- It occurs in safari and chrome, and it does not occur in firefox or opera*

---

## Question:

How can I prevent the browser from jumping the scroll to the top of the page when clicking the radio button's label?

---

## Example code:

#### • [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rob_tb/XkQ7T/)

#### • HTML

```
<div class="rdbut">
    <label class="colour">
        <input id="option-AVGANT1Y2PC" type="radio" name="Multi-licence" value="1 Year 2 PC|+23.99|0" checked="checked" />
        <span>£24.99</span></label>
</div>
<div class="rdbut">
    <label class="colour">
        <input id="option-AVGANT2Y2PC" type="radio" name="Multi-licence" value="2 Year 2 PC|+34.00|0" checked="checked" />
        <span>£35.00</span></label>
</div>
```

#### • CSS

```
.rdbut {
    margin: 0px;
}

.rdbut label {
    float: left;
    width: 65px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline;
}

.rdbut label span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    display: block;
}

.rdbut label input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

.rdbut input:checked+span {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #F7F7F7;
}

.rdbut .colour {
    background-color: #FF8E22;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: CSS has no effect on the page position at clicking. Do you have any Javascript 'attached' to the radio buttons?

Comment: Hi, no none at all. From doing a search i cant seem to find any clear answers.

Comment: Is or can you put it online?

Comment: I have an example on JSfiddle, scroll to the radio button in the result section. http://jsfiddle.net/rob_tb/XkQ7T/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Interesting. I don't know exactly why it behaves that way, but curing the unwanted behavior is easy: exchange the CSS `top` and `left` values of the radio inputs for `visibility: hidden`.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
    #content {
        width: 500px;
    }
    .rdbut {
        margin:0px;
    }
    .rdbut label {
        float:left;
        width:65px;
        margin:4px;
        background-color:#EFEFEF;
        border:none;
        overflow:auto;
        display:inline;
    }
    .rdbut label span {
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding:3px 8px;
        display:block;
    }
    .rdbut label input {
        position:absolute;
        t/op: -9999px;
        l/eft: -9999px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .rdbut input:checked + span {
        background-color:#404040;
        color:#F7F7F7;
    }
    .rdbut .colour {
        background-color:#FF8E22;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <p>"Lorem ipsum" goes here.
        </p>
        <div class="rdbut">
            <label class="colour"><input id="option-AVGANT1Y2PC" type="radio" name="Multi-licence" value="1 Year 2 PC|+23.99|0" checked="checked" />
            <span>£24.99</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="rdbut">
            <label class="colour"><input id="option-AVGANT2Y2PC" type="radio" name="Multi-licence" value="2 Year 2 PC|+34.00|0" checked="checked" />
            <span>£35.00</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="rdbut">
            <label class="colour"><input id="option-AVGANT1Y2PC" type="radio" name="Multi-licence" value="1 Year 2 PC|+23.99|0" checked="checked" />
            <span>£24.99</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XkQ7T/1/.

.
By the way, setting `checked` on every radio button is no use - only the last one is actually checked. And it invalidates your code. Also, you need `form` tags around the group of radio inputs.

Comment: This worked great as I was using this: https://codepen.io/davidicus/pen/pvObpV but wanted my <label>s at the bottom instead of the at the top. visibility: hidden cured the annoying 'jump.' :)

Comment: Don't do this. It breaks accessibility (keyboard and screen readers).

Comment: @John_911 - Not doing this means that normal and disabled users suffer from the radio jump problem, doing this means that only the disabled do?

Comment: Same problem I was facing today and you fix,  work for me. Thanks  :)

Comment: Thank you! I was using opacity: 0; to hide it as I needed it to still be able to be linked to as an anchor, but that was resulting in this jumping.

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem, I use @Frank Conijn's  solution,but if the radio set `visibility: hidden;` or `display:none`,the label(for="#id") not work in IE8, at last, I fix it like this:

```
.rdbut label input {
  position:absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 }
```

do not set `top` value

Comment: IE8? In 2016? The extended support for Windows XP ended on April 8, 2014. And so it did for IE8. You should warn IE8 users that they should use Chrome or Firefox, if they must continue using XP.

Comment: @FrankConijn IE havent seen its prime yet, IE is powerfull and a sleeping giant, people talk about no support, we talk about support, IE is what Chrome never could be, IE has been friendly to developers, IE has a great debugger that never lags, IE is utterly awesome

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 -- Everyone's entitled to their opinion. But I'm talking about IE8.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is not accessible: `visibility: hidden;` will [hide your content from screen readers](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).  Regardless, the trouble is here:

```
.rdbut label input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

**Specifically, the `top: -9999;` is causing the browser to try and go up to that point.**

I like to set a class for hiding stuff like this, with the following parameters.  Then you can just stick it anywhere:

```
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: auto;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note the `top: auto;` which should prevent the jump.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I did, and it worked well and still allowed for accessibility.

```
.hiddenInput {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

That way the input is always in "view" so the label never has to forcibly scroll to it.
The 'top: 0' is optional, for me it defaulted to the middle of my screen, I just put it somewhere explicitly.

Comment: The other ones didn't work for me, but this one did. +1

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!  `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` fixed my issue.  For those that want a good primer on why it is bad to use `visibility: hidden` look no further than this Medium article: https://blog.bitsrc.io/customise-radio-buttons-without-compromising-accessibility-b03061b5ba93

Comment: This is really the best answer. All others break accessibility. There is no need to send the radio button off-screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just add "display:none" to radio button.

```
input[type="radio"]{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you customize your radiobutton, don't hide it from page with display:none and don't use big left:-9999px.

Better use opacity:0, width:1px, height:1px and let the radio be close to your fake-radio button

```
<style>
.radio-button__container{
  position: relative
}
.radio-button{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the browser jumps is that the input (radio or checkbox) and its labels are far away from each other, and when you click the visible `label`, the `input` gets the focus, so the browser goes where the `input` (focus) is.

Change the layout: put the `input`, the `label` and the `::before` element of the label in a grid. The grid fixes the positions, so you can hide the input on the spot. This way the label and the input will not diverge, so focus will not make problem:

```html
<style>
    div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
    input {
        display: none;
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
    }
    label {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    }
    label::before {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        content: "";
        /* all necessary styling for the fancy input*/
    }
    </style>

    <html>
    <div>
       <input type="radio" id="a"><label for="a">Label text</label>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

display: none; or visibility: hidden - > not gonna help you if you need an accessibly :(
It's will fix an issue with page scroll but create an issue for the Screen readers.

This variant works good for me (thanks @James Hang!):

```
    input{
          opacity: 0;
          height: 0;
          width: 0;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
    }
```