# Page position reset on radio selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does the page position reset when making a selection in this jsfiddle, and how do I prevent it?

https://jsfiddle.net/zexvtoz1/21/

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="rating one">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!"><span>&#9733</span></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good"><span>&#9733</span></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh"><span>&#9733</span></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad"><span>&#9733</span></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time"><span>&#9733</span></label>
</fieldset>
```

Potato quality GIF of what's happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8jy.gif

[image]

Edit: new jsfiddle link

Comment: What do you mean by page position reset? I don't see anything happening in the fiddle except the stars being highlighted.

Comment: I don't understand what are u trying to achieve

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz Animated gif is added.

Comment: I dont see any text in jsfiddle please provide it in.

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz New jsfiddle link added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it, but not why it's happening (although I can guess that it's trying to position itself with the radio button "within view").

I changed the following code

```
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  position:absolute;
  top:-9999px;
  clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

to

```
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  position:absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Fiddle with fix https://jsfiddle.net/t4t0dxqz/

[Finally found a thread that clued me in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299567/radio-button-causes-browser-to-jump-to-the-top)

Comment: aww i almost post that answer.! nvm well u finally figured it out :D